# Accessing pointers in struct and getting segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am trying to access the objectName and questionName and I keep getting a segmentation fault. When I use a char array it only prints it the questionName not the objectName. I have allocated memory to everything so it must be to do with how I access these pointers. If someone could explain why I get a segmentation fault that would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
 char *objectName;
 char *questionName; 
 struct node *left_ptr;
 struct node *right_ptr; 
 };

void treePrint(struct node *ptr) 
{
 if (ptr == NULL)
 {
  return;
 }
 else 
 {
  if (ptr -> questionName != NULL)//ptr is a question 
  {
    printf("question: %s\n", ptr -> questionName);

  //now print the yes and no subtrees:
    treePrint(ptr->left_ptr);
    treePrint(ptr->right_ptr);
  }
   else 
  { // ptr is an object
   printf("object: %s\n", ptr -> objectName);
  }
 }
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{ 

 struct node *firstquestion = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 struct node *secondquestion = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

 struct node *firstObject = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 struct node *secondObject = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 struct node *thirdObject = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

 strcpy(firstquestion -> questionName, "Does it have a tail?");
 strcpy(secondquestion -> questionName, "Is it round and edible?");

 strcpy(firstObject -> objectName, "A pangolin");
 strcpy(secondObject -> objectName, "Mandeep");
 strcpy(thirdObject -> objectName, "Orange");

 firstquestion -> left_ptr = firstObject;
 firstquestion -> right_ptr = secondquestion;
 secondquestion -> left_ptr = thirdObject;
 secondquestion -> right_ptr = secondObject;


 treePrint(firstquestion); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not allocated memory for `firstquestion->questionName`, therefore `strcpy(firstquestion -> questionName, "Does it have a tail?");` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to `malloc()` the `questionName`, `objectName` and so on. But you can also do something easier and simlper, use `strdup()` like this

```
ptr->questionName = strdup("Does it have a tail?");
```

One more thing, you need to check the return value of `malloc()` against `NULL`.

NOTE: And please don't use spaces around the `->` operator, it looks terrible. Also, be consistent with white space usage, use enough of it not too little but not too much. Only, be consistent with your own style.

Comment: would I do that in the print method like:                                                                                                        struct node *objectName = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

Comment: @guy NO, you have to allocate the right number of characters, note that `objectName` is of type `char`. Are you trying to do your homework without understanding it? Just to deliver?

Comment: But questionName is in struct so im not sure how to give it a memory block. Usually I declare a new variable and assign it memory as shown

Comment: It doesn't matter to whom you assign the result of `malloc()` as long as you check it's not `NULL` before trying to dereference it, and as long as you write the appropriate data into it. Memory allocation is far from easy to understand. You need to read more, and then try to implement.